# eyed3 for python - how to load selective id3 data from audio file?

Tags: python, tags, metadata, id3, eyed3

I'm using eyed3 module for reading only 'artist name' tag from a music library, but when some files load correctly others fail just at at the beginning, at the state of loading:

```
mp3file = eyed3.load(filepath)
```

for example, reading my library evolves in about 10 different types of errors. output from console:

> eyed3.id3.frames:WARNING: Fixing invalid lyrics language code: ¦Ó
>   
>  eyed3.id3.frames:WARNING: Frame 'RVAD' is not yet supported, using raw
>   
>  Frame to parse eyed3.core:WARNING: FrameHeader: Illegal Frame ID: COM
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: FrameHeader: Illegal Frame ID: CM1
>   
>  eyed3.id3.frames:WARNING: Unknown ID3 frame ID: RGAD
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: GEOB frame does not contain a mime type
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: GEOB frame does not contain a valid mime type
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: FrameHeader: Illegal Frame ID: TT2
>   
>  eyed3.mp3:WARNING: Unable to find a valid mp3 frame
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: Invalid APIC picture type: 78 
>   
>  eyed3.core:WARNING: APIC frame does not contain image data/url

I've made up a work-around for this by loading only the tag that I need ('artist name'), instead of all tags, but is it possible with eyed3?

and btw. do you know any good manual for using this module in Python with examples? because the official site (http://eyed3.nicfit.net) seems quite poor in this case

Comment: it really is a dearth of eyed3 examples to learn from on the net!

Answer (score 4):

As [shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403189/python-eyed3-warning) you can set the error logging level to only log errors, which should remove your warnings.

```
eyed3.log.setLevel("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "artist name only tag".. There is one tag per file from which the artist name may exist. All of the WARNING messages are just that, warnings. The tag is loaded, some values are malformed and so the warning is printed.. but the tag is still loaded and if there is an artist frame you can read it with tag.artist.