# Python Eyed3 Warning

Tags: python, warnings, eyed3

Some of my mp3 files seem to have a non standard genre. When I loop through them (which I have to do in my program) I get tons of warnings like this one :

```
eyed3.id3:WARNING: Non standard genre name: Rock - Punk/Pop-Punk , Rock - Alternative Rock
```

How can I prevent eyed3 to print them?

Edit:
I get this warning when I load a file e.g. :

```
mp3_file = eyed3.load( "path to file" ) #I get a warning when I open the 'wrong' file
```

Answer (score 13):

You can change the log level in eyed3 to only show errors. Try this:

```
eyed3.log.setLevel("ERROR")
```

Comment: Is there a way to catch warnings, as we would with an error?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to check if `file = eyed3.load(filepath)` produces a warning or an error (other than watching terminal output)?