# Python Filter Warnings from third party module 'eyed3'

Tags: python, warnings, eyed3

It's posible to filter, at runtime, the Warnings raised from the imported eyed3 module during a re-taging operation ?

It result in:

> WARNING:eyed3.mp3.headers:Lame tag CRC check failed
>   WARNING:eyed3.id3:Non standard genre name: Roman sentimental

For the sake of information:
The first Warning come from the eyed3.load('song') call. 
(The song it's been mp3 converted in Audacity with the ffmpeg FFmpeg mp3 lame encoder.)
The second from the tag() 'genre' assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Eyed3 Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403189/python-eyed3-warning)

Comment: FYI, for the second warning, Id3 tags have a list of specific genres. If you use one outside of that list, you'll see the message you got there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a log warning you can filter it out by changing the log-level that logger:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("eyed3.mp3.headers").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me tons! I still don't know why I'm getting this warning, and more importantly how to fix it. I'm happy hiding it but I rather just fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this... Really helps